# Vector gets filled with last item only

Tags: java, android

The goal is to fill a vector of Hashtables with Hashtables.

To do so, I iterate over a cursor, put what the cursor finds in a Hashtable and then add the Hashtable to the vector, like so:

```
Vector<Hashtable<String, String>> v = new Vector<Hashtable<String, String>>();
Hashtable<String,String> h = new Hashtable<String,String>();

while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    h.put("name", cursor.getString(0));
    h.put("region", cursor.getString(1));
    h.put("_id", cursor.getString(2));

    v.addElement(h);
}
```

The result is a Vector filled with the last element in the cursor, if the cursor iterates over X elements, then the Vector has X times the last Hashtable created.

Adding this one line solves the problem:

```
Vector<Hashtable<String, String>> v = new Vector<Hashtable<String, String>>();
Hashtable<String,String> h = new Hashtable<String,String>();

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        h = new Hashtable<String,String>();   // <--THIS LINE HERE
        h.put("name", cursor.getString(0));
        h.put("region", cursor.getString(1));
        h.put("_id", cursor.getString(2));

        v.addElement(h);
    }
```

But I don't fully understand why...

Is the vector only keeping pointers to the Hashtables...?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code example, each iteration through the `while` loop populates **the same** `Hashtable` with the contents of the current cursor position. In your second code example, calling the constructor (the `new Hashtable()` part) makes sure that each iteration is populating **a different** `Hashtable` each time.

Note that with collections, it's possible to modify them in ways that aren't immediately obvious. Imagine we have this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add("hello");
    set.add("world");

    Vector<Set<String>> v = new Vector<>();
    v.add(set);

    set.clear();

    System.out.println(v);
}
```

You might be surprised to learn that this prints the following:

> ```
> [[]]
> ```

When you `add()` the `Set` to the `Vector`, nothing happens to "lock" its contents. So further changes to the `Set` affect the `Vector` as well.

Similarly, in your program, after the first loop iteration, your `Vector` will hold a single reference to a `Hashtable` with the contents of the first cursor position. But then your second iteration runs, overwrites the contents of the `Hashtable`, and `add()`s it again. Now your `Vector` will hold two references (to the same `Hashtable`), each with the contents of the second cursor position.

This pattern will repeat until your `while` loop terminates, at which point your `Vector` will have X references (to the same `Hashtable`), each with contents of the last cursor position.

Answer (score 1):

In the first block of code you are just overwriting the same object, so let's say you iterated over the while loop twice. if first h instance has name="a", region="b" and _id="c", then on the next iteration since you do not create a new instance the name, region and _id fields of the object will be overriden by whatever value you assign to them.  Hence you have two items and both have the same values for their attributes.